# Does Windows 8.1 contain updates when downloaded with the Media Creation Tool?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, windows-update, media-creation-tool, spectre

If I download Windows 8.1 (to install on another PC) using Microsoft's Media Creation Tool would it include many recent updates, and of what kind? (I can find no recent answers).  I'm presuming that it would the most recent build number.

Are there any security updates that I should download seperately so I can install them before the machine goes online? I'm particularly thinking of the well-publicised vulnerabilities affecting CPU's, eg. Spectre & Meltdown (it has an intel CPU).

Additional information:

- Creating an ISO with the MCT to reinstall 8.1 on another PC.
- 8.1 PC is currently offline, custom build, with genuine install of 8.1.
- PC is problematic, looked into it a lot, and the general opinion was to reinstall Windows.
- The original 8.1 media is years old, hoping to starting with a newer build and recent updates.
- For security, I would ideally have Windows updates for intel in place, before it goes online if that's possible.
  (Would intel updates come with the ISO as standard?)
- I've found Spectre intel updates for Windows 10, but not for 8.1.

Comment: If I download Windows 8.1 (to install on another PC)  ...........   Reinstalling Windows 8.1 with the Media Creation Link installs all updates.  Your Windows 8.1 is likely OEM and that cannot be moved to another computer.

Comment: @john Thanks for the comment. Apologies, to clarify, I'm not moving Windows 8.1. I'm creating an ISO it on one PC with the MCT, to reinstall on a custom 8.1 PC that is offline at the moment.

Comment: @John Do you mean that I cannot use MCT on a Windows 10 PC to create an up-to-date ISO disc/usb of Windows 8.1? To then reinstall 8.1 on an offline PC that has genuine 8.1, at the moment, but needs reinstalling?

Comment: You should be able to create a Windows 8.1 USB for use on another computer (that is an MCL option) and then use that to install Windows 8.1 on another computer. That should work.

Comment: "I'm presuming that it would the most recent build number." - The build number never changed with cumulative security updates for Windows 7 and Windows 8.  Only cumulative updates for Windows 10 and Windows 11 change the minor build number.  I would not bet money that updates would be downloaded with the Windows 8.1 MCT. However, there are better solutions, to updating an offline machine updating the ISO.

Comment: @Ramhound Re. "better solutions", do you mean downloading all the updates separately to the MCT ISO?

Comment: @Eric - Yes;  There are tools that will make that easy, and since Windows 8.1 updates are far and few between, makes the job relatively painless.

Comment: @Ramhound Are they Microsoft tools you refer to? Where would I find them?

Comment: Free tools are primarily limited to third-party tools.  Paid Microsoft tools do exist though WSUS integration.